# Remove link from active page in menu

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I need the active page in my menu not to be a link.

So let's say I'm on the services page, I need my menu structure to look like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="first leaf"><a href="/mysite/">home</a></li>
    <li class="leaf">services</li>
    <li class="leaf"><a href="/mysite/portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="leaf"><a href="/mysite/contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the [theme_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_link/7) function.
In your template.php file add this. (changing THEME to the name of your theme).

```
function THEME_link($variables) {
  if ((isset($variables['path']) && ($variables['path'] == $_GET['q'] || ($variables['path'] == '<front>' && drupal_is_front_page())))) {
    // Return text instead of link if current menu item active
    return ($variables['options']['html'] ? $variables['text'] : check_plain($variables['text']));
  } else {
    return '<a href="' . check_plain(url($variables['path'], $variables['options'])) . '"' . drupal_attributes($variables['options']['attributes']) . '>' . ($variables['options']['html'] ? $variables['text'] : check_plain($variables['text'])) . '</a>';
  }
}
```