# Don't link menu in the active page

Tags: 8, navigation

My Q is equal as [Remove link from active page in menu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133668/remove-link-from-active-page-in-menu)

> I need the active page in my menu not to be a link.
>
> So let's say I'm on the services page, I need my menu structure to
>   look like this:
>
> ```
> <ul class="menu">
>     <li class="first leaf"><a href="/mysite/">home</a></li>
>     <li class="leaf">services</li>
>     <li class="leaf"><a href="/mysite/portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
>     <li class="leaf"><a href="/mysite/contact">contact</a></li>
> </ul>
> ```

How can I do that in drupal 8?

**Update**
what about this thing in my theme menu--main.html.twig?

```
{% if item.attributes.hasClass('active') %}
<span>{{ item.title }}</span>
{%- else -%}
{{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
{%- endif -%}
```

Answer (score 4):

In D8 the handling of active links is split between php and js, so that the menus can be cached independently from the page they appear on. A solution in php or twig is only possible when you switch off caching of menus, but this is not good for performance. So a better approach is probably in javascript.

Remove the link tag by selecting the links with the class `is-active`:

*mytheme/js/remove-active-links.js*

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.removeActiveLinks = {
    attach: function (context) {

      $(context).find('a.is-active').contents().unwrap();

    }
  };

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

You need to define a dependency on the core active-link.js, which sets the class `is-active`, so that your js file runs later:

*mytheme/mytheme.libraries.yml*

```
remove-active-links:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/remove-active-links.js: { }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupal.active-link
```

---

**Background information**

The js code above is the most basic solution, but it loads jQuery also for anonymous traffic, which is not a problem if you already use it.

If you want to avoid jQuery see [`ActiveLinkResponseFilter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21EventSubscriber%21ActiveLinkResponseFilter.php/class/ActiveLinkResponseFilter/8.7.x), which is a response subscriber adding the class `is-active` for anonymous requests.

You can then alter the result in a custom response subscriber with a lower priority, similar to the js code above.

Comment: Thanks! but I think it's not good solution for SEO?

Comment: Don't think that's bad for SEO, but it doesn't matter, because googlebot crawls javascript for about 2 or 3 years now. And I think as drupal goes ahead with optimizing menu caching strategy with javascript it's best to follow the same path.

Comment: you are right and your solution working so thank you again!

Comment: What do you think about my update?

Comment: The class `active` is for the active trail, not for the active link. I put some background information in the answer for a php solution.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is generated by a twig template, you should see
`{% for item in items %}`
in one of your theme's menu templates, and then do a condition e.g. `{% if item.in_active_trail %}`.  You could probably just check for `item.in_active_trail` in the item variable, but if that's not good enough, just use Kint (from the devel module) to figure out a variable that works for your situation.

Comment: My theme is "businessgroup zymphonies theme" and in links.html.twig i found this
`<ul{{ attributes }}>
    {%- for key, item in links -%}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(key|clean_class) }}>
        {%- if item.link -%}
          {{ item.link }}
        {%- elseif item.text_attributes -%}
          <span{{ item.text_attributes }}>{{ item.text }}</span>
        {%- else -%}
          {{ item.text }}
        {%- endif -%}
      </li>
    {%- endfor -%}
  </ul>`

Comment: This is probably only something that theme maintainer can solution, then.