# javascript code does not execute for authenticated users

Tags: javascript

Maybe someone of you has already encountered this weird problem that I am having. I have javascript code that runs fine when you are an anonymous user and no longer works when authenticating. The library is loaded, but the code does not execute. Does this speak to anyone?
My drupal version is 8.9.2 and the code in question :

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
Drupal.behaviors.toto = {
attach(context, settings) {
  $('.block--toto ul', context).once('toto-behavior').each(function() {

      let toto = $('.block--toto ul');
    let istotoActive = toto.find('li.is-active');

    toto
      .wrap('<div class="dropdown"></div>')
      .closest('.dropdown')
      .prepend('<button href="#toto" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">' + istotoActive.attr('hreflang') + '</button>');

    toto
      .addClass('dropdown-menu')
      .find('li').addClass('dropdown-item')
      .find('a').addClass('dropdown-link');
    $('.block--toto li').each(function () {
      $(this).on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('.dropdown')
          .find('.dropdown-toggle').text($(this).text())
      })
    })

  });
}
```

};
})(jQuery, Drupal);

Thanks for help

Comment: did you clear cache after make new js changes? Might be js aggregation cause issue.

Comment: @ARUN 
when i clear the caches the first time the code actually runs. But the problem reappears when I refresh the page

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate the Admin Toolbar or Menu "active" states? Both of them are not rendered serverside, but updated asynchronously by JS. It can happen that a block container like `.block--toto` exists and the behavior triggers, but that an `is-active` class is added afterwards by JS, after your behavior has triggered.

Comment: When logged in you have a lot more Drupal.behaviors calls with different contexts and your code is not correctly handling it. The first line is correct, but then you assign `toto` globally instead of `toto = $(this)`. Later it's the other way, the first line is missing context `$('.block--toto li')` while the rest seems to be OK.

Comment: A solution for @Hudri comment could be that you declare a dependency on `core/drupal.active-link`, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/235108/47547

Comment: Thanks you gentlemen ! As you said @4k4 several Drupal.behaviors call with differents contexts when we log. It would seem in my case that the context was not the expected one. The issue was resolved by removing the context.